# PowerPC Macintosh code injection

Tags: injection, macos, powerpc

I'm reverse engineering a game for the old PowerPC MacOS 9 pc via the static analysis in IDA Pro windows but I want to inject code during runtime(for example via the dynamic library) in an emulator for MacOS(SheepShaver for example). How can I do that?